# How to move later created branch before first commit on master branch in git?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have my master branch `master`and a branch `originalCode`. The parent of the `originalCode` branch is `master`:

```
                  F  originalCode
                 / 
A - B - C - D - E  master
```

Now I want to move my `originalCode` branch with commit `F` before the commit `A`.
I already tried around with rebasing and merging, but I could not get it to work and I could not find a similar question regarding this.

The goal is to have a common history to see exactly what changes from the original code (some scripts) have been made. When I started with checkin in, I already started with an external modified version.

Comment: This is slightly unclear - you already have a common history!

Comment: OriginalCode branch contains the unmodified original code which I did not had at first check in. I only later realized that I had already a modified version when I started adding it to a Repo. The code in the branch should have been the very first commit.

Comment: You should understand that in Git, branches are references to *single commits*, so in your case `originalCode` is another name for `F` and `master` is another name for `E`. The graph should be drawn a little differently to be accurate, I'll show you how.

Comment: What commit is the parent commit of F?

Comment: Doing verbatim what you ask would involve rewriting the history of the `master` branch, which probably is a bad idea.  As @Oliver said, you already have a potentially linear history in `master`, so why do you want to move commit `F` back in time?

Comment: Are there any other commits before `A` or is it the initial commit of the repository?

Comment: A is the first (root) commit in the repo. 
@DAle The parent of commit F is the master branch
I am aware that this potentially rewrites the history of the master branch. I want to move it because I want to have the original as the first commit and not my slightly modified version with which I started! 
I want just have F-A-B-C-D-E , so that I have a straight line

Comment: *“I am aware that this potentially rewrites the history of the master branch”* – Strike the “potentially”. This effectively recreates every commit, and with that the whole repository. This makes every clone incompatible with the new version. Are you really aware of the implications of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Create and switch to a new branch `reordered`, which will later contain the reordered commits, to point to the same commit (`F`) as `originalCode`:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b reordered originalCode
   ```

   The commit graph now looks like this:

   ```
                     F  originalCode, reordered
                    / 
   A - B - C - D - E  master
   ```

   This is so that `master` and `originalCode` remain untouched. In case something goes wrong, you can simply delete `reordered` and start over.
2. Interactively rebase `reordered`, positioning `F` before `A`:

   Since `A` is the root commit, you need to specify the `--root` option.

   ```
   $ git rebase -i --root reordered
   ```

   This will open a text editor containing something like this:

   ```
   pick d14a5dd A
   pick 57b6bd9 B
   pick de4e672 C
   pick 6fc8c1f D
   pick 453da48 E
   pick d2443c0 F
   ```

   Cut the line with `F` and paste it above the line with `A`. Then save and exit the editor to continue.

   Depending on the actual contents of your commits, you may need to resolve merge conflicts during the rebase.
3. Once the rebase is done, the commit graph should look like this:

   ```
                     F  originalCode
                    / 
   A - B - C - D - E  master

   F'- A'- B'- C'- D'- E'  reordered
   ```

   Note that there are two series of commits that have no common ancestor, because of the `--root` rebase.
4. Reassure yourself that there are no differences in content between `reordered` and `master`.

   ```
   $ git diff reordered master
   ```

   This should produce no output.

   (*Edit: I suspect you want the contents of `master` as the "newest" version, not the contents of `originalCode`, so I changed the `diff` accordingly.)*

   If there is a difference, you may have done something wrong while resolving merge conflicts.

   You may also inspect the individual commits using a graphical repository browser like `gitk`.
5. Once you are satisfied with the state of the `reordered` branch, you can either delete `originalCode` and `master`, followed by renaming `reordered` to `master`, or you can move `master` to point to the same commit (`E'`) as `reordered` and delete the `originalCode` and `reordered` branches.

   ```
   $ git checkout -B master reordered
   $ git branch -D reordered originalCode
   ```

   The end result should be a commit graph like this:

   ```
   F'- A'- B'- C'- D'- E'  master
   ```

---

To address the concerns raised by some commenters:

In case there are other people who have cloned the repository and depend on the `master` branch, you should not delete or move it like shown in step 5 above.

Instead (after step 4) I would propose to merge the new `reordered` branch into `master`, to provide an alternative history leading to the current state, but keeping the original history as well:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge reordered
$ git branch -d reordered
```

Result:

```
    A - B - C - D - E - G  master
                      /
F'- A'- B'- C'- D'- E'
```

Comment: Thanks, after I deleted the other branches my history is now as I wanted to have it.

Answer (score 0):

You do the following:

Create a new root commit containing the original code base:

```
git checkout originalCode
git checkout --orphan originalCode2
git commit -m "Original code of project foo"
```

Now we have to transplant the history leading to `master` on top of this new root. For this purpose, we graft commit `A` on top of `originalCode2`:

```
echo $(git rev-parse A originalCode2) >> .git/info/grafts
```

and then *rewrite* the history to make the new parentship permanent:

```
git filter-branch master
```

Now you have the intended history. Note that this *rewrites history* and all caveats concerning published rewritten history apply.

Finally, you should remove the last line of `.git/info/grafts` (which was written in the above steps). It is most probably the only line, then you can just remove `.git/info/grafts`.

It may be possible to use `git rebase --root originalCode2 master` or some variation involving `--root` instead of `filter-branch`, but I have no experience with this rebase variant.